# Draw Text on scaled Canvas on Android

Tags: android, text, android-canvas, scale

i am drawing a text on a scaled canvas like this:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint.getTextBounds(fct.getText(), 0, fct.getText().length(), bounds);

            float scaleX = postcard.getWidth() / fct.getContainerWidth();
            float scaleY = postcard.getHeight() / fct.getContainerHeight();

            float textXpos = fct.getPositionX();
            float textYpos = fct.getPositionY();

            float rotateX = textXpos + bounds.exactCenterX();
            float rotateY = textYpos + bounds.exactCenterY();

            canvas.save();

            canvas.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
            canvas.rotate(fct.getRotation(), rotateX, rotateY);
            canvas.drawText(fct.getText(), textXpos, textYpos, paint);

            canvas.restore();
```

The X position of the drawn text is completly correct but the Y position is wrong.

The text is drawn above the expected position.

So how to draw it correctly?

Comment: can you draw the text before scaling ?

Comment: not working... scaling is just not taking effect on the text